Katalon test case not running, terminates immediately
I'm using Katalon 9.7 and every time I run any test case I go this error
click to view image
There is no output in the Console.
The only output I got in event log is "Launcher status after execution process completed: Terminated".
I also tried katalon run as administrator but nothing changed.
While recording browser is launching but after saving the test case when I try to run it gets terminated.

It seems that the issue you are experiencing is caused by the latest version of Katalon, which may not be stable yet. Try downloading a lower version of Katalon, perhaps (9.5.0).
You can check it here: https://github.com/katalon-studio/katalon-studio/tags

I had a similar issue
try to Set a different JRE for test projects

Go to Katalon Studio > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs.
Click on the button Add....
in the Add JRE dialog, select Standard VM.
Browse to the Home folder of the JRE you wish to add (it was java 22 and i change it to 17) .
Click Finish.

here is more details on how to set a new default JRE
